# Is there a single ortholattice that translates quantum logic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, algebraic-logic

It is known that Boolean Algebras are related to classical logic, and that the two-valued Boolean algebra is sufficient to determine whether a sequent is derivable in classical logic.

The same happens with intuitionistic logic and Heyting algebras, and we have a similar result to classic logic saying that a sequent is derivable if and only if it is true in the real numbers Heyting algebra (topological space of open sets of $\mathbb{R}$).

I'm starting my study in minimal quantum logic (following Dalla Chiara's approach) and would like to know if there is a similar result for a specific ortholattice.

Thank you.

Comment: If I had to guess, probably the lattice of closed subspaces of an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space? I don't know exactly what goes into "minimal quantum logic" though